# Cant login, Broken Pipe?

Tags: 12.04, pipe

Okay, so I'm really stuck on this one. So yesterday wile I was playing Kerbal Space Program, the game crashed, so I did a hard shutdown (holding the power button). When I turned it on, it booted just fine to the login screen, but when I went to click login, it gives me an error message, saying that "could not write bites: broken pipes" and goes back to the login screen. So I tried going on to the guest account, and that did work, so its just my account... I already looked around on the net for answers, and I tried one where it was because there were removed packages, but when I checked, nothing was removed, ever. So I'm completely lost here. Please help!

Comment: The full error message was this:          Could not write bytes: Broken pipe     [return]       * Starting the Winbind daemon winbind      [return]       saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned      [return]        Checking battery state...                        That's where it ends. Where it says [return], that means new line

Answer (score 1):

After creating a new user in recovery mode I noticed that doing `startx` with my own user but not others threw this error: `xauth: error in locking authority file /home/Connor/.Xauthority` What fixed my problem was deleting the `~/.Xauthority` file in my home directory - a new one was generated with correct permissions and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
You can go to `recovery mode` and then select the option of

`network   Enable networking`

it will connect to network (but you will need wired connection for this)

and then select

`dpkg     repair broken packages`

it will check the packages and if possible it will repair the broken packages ..So try this approach!

If this does not help then there is other way..Which is **not a complete solution but will solve your problem**...

1.Go to recovery mode.

2.select `Drop to root shell`

3.Now you will get command prompt with **ROOT** privileges

4.Now create a new user

`adduser <newusername>`

enter the proper Information(If you have done this already then jump to step 5 directly)

5.Now user cp command to copy your data into new users home directory

`cp -r /home/olduser/* /home/newuser/`

6.Now delete the old user

`deluser <olduser>`

delete his directories if you want (but make sure your all data is copied properly)

`rm -rf /home/olduser/*`

7.Done Now just reboot and you should get new account!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still does the same thing...

Comment: Go to recovery mode, select `drop to root shell` and create the  new user by using `adduser newusername` command. Now after rebooting try to login into that user. If you are able to log in then from that user copy your home directory and delete the old user..This is not a proper solution but I think it will solve your problem... :)

Comment: Sweet, so I got the new account. But how can I copy it over? I don't have permission to mess with the old account. So how can I copy a folder in terminal with the cp function?

Comment: Answer updated!

Comment: It sorta worked, but I can't use chrome or Firefox and some other programs...

Comment: Why? Are those programs also giving the same broken pipe error? Try reinstalling some program and check if that helps!

Comment: On Firefox, it says that the directory doesn't exist, and chrome just doesn't do anything...   Ill try and reinstall them and see if that helps

Comment: I think I figured out where the problem lies. When I try to startx, I get an error I don't get with other accounts...   "xauth: error in locking authority file /home/Connor/.Xauthority"          I already tried replacing that file with ones from other accounts, but it didn't work. How can I fix this?